# MacBookPro Pro A1278 - Wifi connection "dropped" when "idle"

Tags: macos, network, wifi, high-sierra

Is it "normal" for the Wi-Fi connection to "need" reconnection when the Mac is "idle" for a brief period?

It is the same when the Mac is on Ethernet / LAN connection as well as on a USB Wi-Fi adaptor?

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: Define "idle for a brief period."  Do you mean "sleep"?

Comment: Not "sleep" as in "lid closed" and "reopened". When browsing and if 
keyboard/touch pad" is inactive for a while, to navigate to other web page, the screen prompts "you are not connected to internet". Could this be due to a "time out" setting?

Comment: what is the "inactive for a while period" *specifically*?  A couple seconds?  A few mins?  Also, you don't need to close the lid to put the MB to sleep.

Comment: Guess, the MB may have gone to sleep but the web page is visible (screen not blank). In terms of inactivity, its just a few minutes.

Comment: Ok...let's try another way.  In System Preferences >> Energy Saver, what's the time setting for "Computer Sleep"

Comment: What is the version of macOS currently running on your MacBookPro?

Comment: computer sleep set at 10 minutes

Comment: Running on macOS 10.13.3

Comment: Ok...sleep is set for 10 mins.  Use a clock, stopwatch timer, etc. and make a note of when a period of inactivity begins and when Wi-Fi drops.  Is it 10 mins?

Comment: Yes. Wifi drops at 10 minutes.